# Addeed into QTableWidget is wrong

Tags: python, qt, sqlalchemy, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have the fololloiwng code anf my query work fine:

```
    ###initilize Objects
    self.dbObj = DbAbsLayer()
    self.tableObj = MaterialsTable(dict()) 

    ####making queries, one for count row, another for result row
    query = self.dbObj.session.query(MaterialsTable)
    rowCounter = self.dbObj.session.query(MaterialsTable)
    for attr , val in tmpDict.items():
        query = query.filter(getattr(MaterialsTable,attr).like("%%%s%%" % val)).all()
        rowCounter = rowCounter.filter(getattr(MaterialsTable,attr).like("%%%s%%" % val)).count()
    ##### commit my queries
    self.dbObj.session.commit()
    ####setting up my QtableWidget 
    searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setRowCount(rowCounter)
    searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
    ######inserting into QtableWidget
    for row in range(rowCounter):
        for result in query:
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_fromUtf8(result.name))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,0,item)

            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_fromUtf8(integerToPersian(result.bought_price)))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,1,item)

            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("date")#result.bought_date)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,2,item)


            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_fromUtf8(integerToPersian(result.stock)))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,3,item)
            print result.stock
            print integerToPersian(result.stock)
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_fromUtf8(integerToPersian(result.minimum_bound)))
            item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            searchFrameObject.tableWidget.setItem(row,4,item)
            print result.minimum_bound
```

In my loop i `print result.stock` and `result.minimum.bound` i can see everything that i have in DB can i see in `PHPMyAdmin`, But when i add to `QTableWidget`, i see added last result.

**My question** is , how can i add every result into `QTableWidget`?

Comment: Unfortunately, i found http://www.marcogiordanotd.com/blog/uncategorized/looping-with-qtablewidgetitem Do you have any idea? Or did you use setItem in loop before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you doing wrong:

```
for row in range(rowCounter):
    for result in query:
```

You write all results from `query` over the previous `result` in every row, so that is why you can see only last result.

Possible solution (assuming `query` is array):

```
for row in range(rowCounter):
    result = query[row]
    item = ....
    .....
```

that way every result contained in `query` will be written in one (new) row (5 columns). 
You need to check if your `rowCounter` is the same length like your `query` (it should be if you want to show one result per row)

If you still do not understand what is wrong, feel free to ask :)

Comment: `print result.stock` print 1 2 3 for each three loop because for each result.stock i stored 1 , 2 and 3 in DB, be sure my query is true.

Comment: `    for result in query[row]:
TypeError: 'MaterialsTable' object is not iterable` ,When i test with rowCounter i get true result.

Comment: Ofcourse it prints "1 2 3", but when row = 0, you write result (one with result.stock=1) in row. Result is in for loop, so it will write second result (one with result.stock=2) in the same row. Once again, result (one with result.stock=3) will be written over last one but also in the same row. So, it will print "1 2 3" but only result with  result.stock=3 will be shown in tableWidget.

Comment: i did not say to loop result through `query[row]`  , I said `result = query[row]` . Look at my answer "Possible solution"

Comment: just change that one line, it should work (populate one result per one row). also, `rowCounter` should be length of `query` (as I can see you  are populating table only with results)